# Extract Mustache variable for use in Django template tag

Tags: python, django, algolia

I am implementing Algolia's search API for Django, and I have a certain Mustache variable `{{ObjectID}}` that corresponds to IDs for search results. I can only use via `{% verbatim %} {{ObjectID}} {% endverbatim %}` without having Django's template syntax conflicting.

However, I also need this variable to construct a url for the ID, but the issue is that I can't easily pass the Mustache variable into a form usable directly with Django's templates. As an example, simply doing

```
{% url "appName:method" {{ObjectID}} %}
```

conflicts with Django's template syntax, but trying to ivnoke `verbatim` via

```
{% url "appName:method" {%verbatim %} {{ObjectID}} {% endverbatim %} %}
```

does not work either, since calling a template tag in a template tag is disallowed.

I am also unable to store `{{ObjectID}}` as a temporary variable with a method or offshore `url` to a separate method, e.g.

```
function generate (objectID){
    return "{% url 'appName:method' objectID %}"
}

//usage of method

<a href = "generate({% verbatim %}{{ObjectID}} {% endverbatim %})">link</a>
```

since Django will process the `url` on sight and throw `NoReverseMatch` since `objectID` is not defined by Algolia yet. Is there a way to extract `{{ObjectID}}` such that it can be piped back into Django's `url` constructor?

NOTE: My implementation of Algolia doesn't directly interact with Django's databases, but rather its own indexing of the database that it stores separately. More information on [`algoliasearch-django`'s Github](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use something like this in the view and pass the value to the template:

`reverse('appName:method', args=[1337]).replace('1337', '{{ObjectID}}')`

If you must do it only in the template and you can be sure that the `{{ObjectID}}` part will always be at the end of the URL, you can do it like this:

`{% url "appName:method" 1337 as my_url %}
<a href="{{ my_url|slice:":-5" }}{% verbatim %}{{ObjectID}}{% endverbatim %}/">...</a>`

Note that the above template code assumes a trailing slash.

Comment: what's the significance of `1137`?

Comment: Just something that's not going to be elsewhere in the URL, but still match the regex of the URL pattern. You can use whatever you want there.

Comment: would I also pass the value obtained via `reverse` as a value in the view's `context`?

Comment: Yes, you would do that